# Use previous "path" in a command

Tags: bash, command-history

A couple of years ago, a former coworker told me a trick in Bash that I completely forgot how to do it. The idea is that when you type a path, in the next command you can use some shortcut to automatically put that path there as well.

Let's say I create the directory `/tmp/test`. If then I want to move a file there, I could `mv file [shortcut that puts /tmp/test]`

What's that shortcut?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's <kbd>Esc</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>

```
mkdir mydir
cd [here you press ESC+.] mydir
```

Also see : [How to use arguments from previous command? | Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4009412/5559867)

Answer (score 3):

You can use`$_`, which is the last argument of the previous command:

```
$ mkdir /tmp/test
$ echo "$_"
  /tmp/test
```

From my */usr/share/doc/bash/bashref.html#Special-Parameters-1*:

> _ ($_, an underscore.) At shell startup, set to the absolute pathname used to invoke the shell or shell script being executed as passed in
>   the environment or argument list. Subsequently, expands to the last
>   argument to the previous command, after expansion. Also set to the
>   full pathname used to invoke each command executed and placed in the
>   environment exported to that command. When checking mail, this
>   parameter holds the name of the mail file.

Alternatively, if you're in `set -o emacs` mode, you can use *readline*'s
**yank-last-arg (M-., M-_)**.

Comment: I'm looking for the terminal shortcut. Whenever I used that shortcut, the path was automatically put in the command, so you see the the path, not just `$_`

Comment: @yzT Shortcut added (although typing `$_` might be easier than pressing that shortcut).